# is this possible to override the amount dynamically by using the non hosted encrypted button

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

i want Paypal to accept a user enter amount.but it not accepting while redirecting to paypal the amount is blank.is this possible to  override the amount dynamically by using the non hosted encrypted button.can anyone help .i m helpless

This  is my form

```
       <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target=_blank>
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="<?PHP echo $encrypted; ?>">

     <div  class="paypal_list2">   
     <input type="hidden"><h3>Enter the amount</h3><br /> </div>
     <input id="total" class="paypal_input_1" type="text" value="" name="amount">

    <input class="paypal_btn" type="image"src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">                                  
     </form>
```

This my php code

```
           <?php

    $MY_KEY_FILE = "/home/khader/smsmobilebase/certs/private-key.pem";

    $MY_CERT_FILE = "/home/khader/smsmobilebase/certs/publi-cert.pem";

    $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE = "/home/khader/smsmobilebase/certs/paypal_cert_pem.txt";

     $OPENSSL = "/usr/bin/openssl";


     $form = array('cmd' => '_xclick','business' => 'roki_1347003608_biz@gmail.com','cert_id' => '6BPQP9KEEBCJ6','currency_code' => 'USD',
'no_shipping' => '1',
'item_name' => 'PayNow',


'cancel_return' => 'http://mobiletool.xichlomobile.com/',
'amount' => "'$amount'"
           );

  $encrypted = paypal_encrypt($form);

 function paypal_encrypt($hash)
   {

         global $MY_KEY_FILE;
         global $MY_CERT_FILE;
         global $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE;
         global $OPENSSL;


       if (!file_exists($MY_KEY_FILE)) {
      echo "ERROR: MY_KEY_FILE $MY_KEY_FILE not found\n";
    }
       if (!file_exists($MY_CERT_FILE)) {
      echo "ERROR: MY_CERT_FILE $MY_CERT_FILE not found\n";
        }
        if (!file_exists($PAYPAL_CERT_FILE)) {
       echo "ERROR: PAYPAL_CERT_FILE $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE not found\n";
         }

      $data = "";
      foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
      if ($value != "") {
     //echo "Adding to blob: $key=$value\n";
    $data .= "$key=$value\n";
        } 
     }

     $openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
                "-outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n) | " .
                "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";

          exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);

         if (!$error) {
        return implode("\n",$output);

          print $hash;
           } else {
             return "ERROR: encryption failed";
          }
                }
             ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax calls to update the `encrypted` field every time user changes the `amount`
. Doing this with a library like jQuery is easy:

```
$('input[name=amount]').change( function () {

   $.ajax({
     url: "http://mydomain.com/encrypter.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: { amount: $('input[name=amount]').val() }
   }).done(function ( data ) {
     $('input[name=enctypted]').val(data);
   });

});
```

Comment: You have to use jquery or a similar javascript library. You can start learning jquery from here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp